# what the script might look like to pull the schema information from a Derby database?

Tags: database, derby

What script should I use to get schema information from derby database. I have local derby database created by using client/server mode. I can look derby database in Db-visualizer where I can run SQL scripts for querying DB.

However, unable to find SQL script to pull schema information like in oracle:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, DATA_LENGTH
FROM USER_TAB_COLS
ORDER BY table_name
```

Comment: If in doubt, check the manual: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/rrefsistabs38369.html

Comment: Another reasonable option is to use dblook: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/tools/ctoolsdblook.html Still another option is to use ij's "show tables" command: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/tools/rtoolsijcomrefshow.html

Comment: Hello Bryan, I only able to retrieve table names, table id, table type etc. using following SQL script: SELECT "TABLEID", "TABLENAME", "TABLETYPE", "SCHEMAID", "LOCKGRANULARITY" FROM "SYS"."SYSTABLES" ORDER BY "TABLENAME";  Can you suggest script to retrieve those table's COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, TYPE_NAME, and COLUMN_SIZE